# HTMX event listener only triggered once

Tags: javascript, htmx

I have the following div in my DOM whose sole purpose is to make a GET request when the "send-message" event is emitted:

```
<div
    hx-get="https://catfact.ninja/fact" 
    hx-trigger="send-message from:document"
    hx-swap="none"
></div>
```

I'm expecting `GET https://catfact.ninja/fact` to be fired off every time the "send-message" event is emitted.

Instead, the request **is only fired the first time the event is emitted** since the element was loaded. Every subsequent event emission does not trigger the div's HTMX event listener.

As a sanity check, I have this listener log to the console every time the event gets emitted:

```
document.addEventListener("send-message", () => {
    console.log("send-message event emitted in document");
});
```

### EDIT: minimum reproducible example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.2" integrity="sha384-L6OqL9pRWyyFU3+/bjdSri+iIphTN/bvYyM37tICVyOJkWZLpP2vGn6VUEXgzg6h" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const sendMessageEvent = new Event("send-message");
        const handleKeypress = (event) => {
            if (event.key === "Enter") {
                event.preventDefault();
                document.dispatchEvent(sendMessageEvent)
            }
        };
        document.addEventListener("keypress", handleKeypress);
        document.addEventListener("send-message", () => {
            console.log("send-message event emitted in document");
        });
    </script>
    <div 
        hx-get="https://catfact.ninja/fact" 
        hx-trigger="send-message from:document"
        hx-swap="none"
    />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps it's cached? Check the network tab in your browser's devtools.

Comment: I had dev tools opened already, it doesn't seem like the request is cached. The div itself is also unchanged after the first HTTP request.

Comment: Can you please include the code responsible for triggering the event? thx

Comment: I've edited my response now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that "sendMessageEvent" event is still the same event every time it gets emitted. So when the HTMX listener is triggered, it already stored the div in a `handledFor` array for that event and therefore treats the action as already handled.

The solution is just to emit a new event every time by doing `document.dispatchEvent(new Event("send-message"));`.